# NoneType not subscriptable error only if in the scope of try/except clauses

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sqlite

For some reason, when I run the following script I don't get any `TypeError` exceptons and my application runs without problems. (I'm using sqlite3 for the database and Flask for the application itself.)

```
my_list = []
for dat in data:
    c.execute("""SELECT some_data FROM data_table WHERE date='{}'""".format(dat))
    my_list.append(c.fetchone()[0])
 return my_list
```

It seems as though for certain dates, there isn't any data, so it's totally possible for there to be the occasional `NoneType`. The issue is that when I change my code to the following, that's when I get the `NoneType not subscriptable` error.

```
my_list = []
for dat in data:
    c.execute("""SELECT some_data FROM data_table WHERE date='{}'""".format(dat))
    try:
        my_list.append(round(c.fetchone()[0]))
    except:
        my_list.append(c.fetchone()[0])
return my_list
```

Hypothetically, if it runs into a `NoneType` object it would branch to the `except` clause and then have the same result as the original block of code. Instead, I get this error and it breaks my Flask application. If someone could please explain what's going on that would be awesome!

Comment: Heads-up: You are also opening yourself up to SQL injection attacks. See the added side note in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`c.fetchone()` can return `None` if there are no more rows to return. If your `SELECT` query produces just a single row, *and* if `round()` raised an exception, then calling `c.fetchone()` *again* can lead to `None` being returned in the `except` handler. The issue here is that calling `c.fetchone()` *multiple times* won't result in the same first row being returned for subsequent calls.

Call `c.fetchone()` once, and test if it returned a value other than `None` before doing anything with it:

```
c.execute("""SELECT some_data FROM data_table WHERE date='{}'""".format(dat))
row = c.fetchone()
if row is not None:
    try:
        my_list.append(round(row[0]))
    except ValueError:  # value that can't be rounded
        continue
```

Note that it is almost always a bad idea to use a blanket `except` statement. Catch only the expected exceptions, never anything more. You could easily be masking memory errors or blocking interrupts now.

Side note: you are wide open for [SQL injection attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). Do **not** use string formatting to interpolate values, *always* use SQL parameters to have the database driver take care of escaping values properly:

```
c.execute("""SELECT some_data FROM data_table WHERE date=?""", (dat,))
```

The `?` question mark is a SQL parameter placeholder, and the tuple passed in as the second argument the parameter values.

Comment: Thanks you're answer was super helpful, but the string formatting doesn't accept user input. It is only to loop through  items from list "data" that I assigned earlier. Unless I'm mistaken, this would prevent any SQL injection attack correct?

Comment: That list could still have been sourced, directly or indirectly, from untrusted data. And if it isn’t right now, it may in the future and your handling of the list is overlooked. It is always better to use parameters.  Also, using parameters makes it possible for the database engine to cache the query plan for that query, as well as make other optimisations.